# Ruby module defined in block?

Tags: ruby, module, block

I've seen a ruby block that looks something like:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|

   module MyModule      
   end

end
```

What is the effect of declaring a module like that inside of a block?

EDIT:

Specifically I had a block to do some cleanup when the VM was terminated, and it looks like

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|

  # vagrant config stuff

   module Vagrant
     module Provisioners
      class ChefClient < Chef
        def cleanup
          # cleanup here
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If the module is defined outside of the Vagrant::Config block I get the error

```
'<module:Provisioners>': uninitialized constant Vagrant::Provisioners::Chef (NameError)
```

And I'm not sure why declaring the module inside the run block made a difference.

Answer (score 1):

It will will conditionally define the module. Remember that blocks are not necessarily executed, it is up to the target method to decide.

While your particular example is perfectly valid Ruby, organizing things like that can lead to confusion. It would be better to have that defined outside of the block for reasons of clarity.

Comment: +1 for clarity reasons. Clarity pays off in reduced maintenance, and that should always be considered.

Comment: So in this particular example, I was doing trying to add a cleanup block to a vagrant script and I was getting an uninitialized constant when the module was outside the block. I'll edit the question to include the specifics.

Comment: It could be what you're trying to reference isn't actually loaded until `Vagrant::Config.run` has started to execute.

Comment: Where is `Chef` supposed to live? To inherit from a class it must already be defined. Also, you can usually collapse multiple `module` namespacing calls into a single line like: `class Vagrant::Provisioners::ChefClient` This avoids kicking everything in a few indents for no reason.

Comment: I think you may be right that the Chef class isn't available in Vagrant::Config.run. I'm not sure where Chef actually "lives" - I just copied this from an example page. Though I will try collapsing the module namespacing. Thanks.

Comment: You might be missing a `require 'chef'` or `gem 'chef'` call somewhere in there.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not exactly sure what kind of magic Vagrant is doing behind the scenes...for this particular case, it's probably easier to just to include it within the run block since I know that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, Modules are useful to provide a new namespace for variables and constants. I'd say that was the reason.

Comment: You're talking about modules in general, not why someone would declare a module within a block.

Comment: Well, *why* someone did it is unknown so we're all guessing as to their reason. We can just suggest possibilities.